# How to making <v-list-item> menus responsive when scrolling down in vue-fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullpage.js

I am creating a homepage using vuetify and vue-fullpage.js

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHVbR.png)

When you click on the menu, go to the page and active pink color.

But... How to making  menus responsive when scrolling down..

**Main.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-navigation-drawer nav app floating>
      <menu-bar  />
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-container fluid>
      <full-page :options="options" id="fullpage" fluid>
        <div class="section" v-bind="user">
          <intro-page :userInfo="user[0].name" />
        </div>
        <div class="section" v-bind="user">
          <about-page :userInfo="user" />
        </div>
        <div class="section" v-bind="skill">
          <skill-page :skillInfo="skill" />
        </div>
        <div class="section" v-for="(project, index) in projects" :key="index">
          <project-page :projectInfo="project" />
        </div>
      </full-page>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MenuBar from "@/components/MenuBar.vue";
import IntroPage from "@/components/IntroPage.vue";
import AboutPage from "@/components/AboutPage.vue";
import SkillPage from "@/components/SkillPage.vue";
import ProjectPage from "@/components/ProjectPage.vue";

export default {
  name: "Main",
  components: {
    MenuBar,
    IntroPage,
    AboutPage,
    SkillPage,
    ProjectPage
  },
  data() {
    return {
      options: {
        anchors: ["About", "Contact", "Skill", "Project"],
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

../src/views/Main.page menu-bar Component

**MenuBar.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-card flat id="menu">
    <v-list>
      <v-list-item-group  color="pink">
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(item, index) in items"
          :key="item.title"
          :href="link[index]"
          activator
          class="overflow-y-auto"
        >
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title"
              ><a v-bind:href="link[index]"></a
            ></v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-item-group>
    </v-list>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      drawer: true,
      items: [
        { title: "About", icon: "mdi-help-box" },
        { title: "Contact", icon: "mdi-phone" },
        { title: "Skill", icon: "mdi-gavel" },
        { title: "Project", icon: "mdi-folder-pound" }
      ],
      link: ["#About", "#Contact", "#Skill", "#Project"],
      right: false,
      permanent: true,
      background: false
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 30%;
  left: 20%;
}
</style>
```

How to making  menus responsive when scrolling down?